# option requires an argument error

Tags: bash, shell

I wrote a shell script to do something. Everything works fine! A part of my code is something like this, so that I can pass options and arguments to it:

```
while getopts "a:b:c" opt
do
 case $opt in
  a) AA=$OPTARG ;;
  b) BB=$OPTARG ;;
  c) CC=$OPTARG ;;
 esac
done
shift $(expr $OPTIND - 1)
```

But now I want to add an option, say `d` and I don't want it to use any argument, as the code shows below, but it ends with an error, complaining `option requires an argument error -- d` It seems that getopts can't do that.

```
while getopts "a:b:c:d" opt
do
 case $opt in
  a) AA=$OPTARG ;;
  b) BB=$OPTARG ;;
  c) CC=$OPTARG ;;
  d) DD="ON" ;;
 esac
done
shift $(expr $OPTIND - 1)
```

What should I do then? What is the common practice if I want both option types, one can accept argument, while the other doesn't need argument?

Comment: Your code works fine, please post the *actual* code that is failing.

Comment: Works fine for me also. Your first code example doesn't, though - this is because the colon in the argument to `getopts` represents that the preceding option has an associated argument. ie `getopts a:b:c` means options -a and -b require arguments, and -c does not.

Comment: Confusing at first as above code is correct, i.e., `getopts "a:b:c:d"` with `d` being a fixed character argument. If code had `getopts "a:b:d:c"`, it would have resulted in the error which user is describing in the first place!

Answer (score 57, accepted):

The `:` in the `getopts` specifier is *not* a separator. From `man getopts`:

> if a character is followed by a colon, the option is expected to have an argument, which should be separated from it by white space.

So if you want an option which doesn't take an argument, simply add the character. If you want it to take an argument, add the character followed by `:`.

Comment: WOW, amazing, you guys understand all, even if I asked the wrong question by giving a wrong sample code, you still can figure out what's really happening, cool!

Comment: It's also amazing that Bash scripting has such granularity,
and a simple language construct to express it,
which in most higher languages would result in many
more lines of code to, accomplish.

Answer (score 2):

This would have happened if you had a colon after the `d` in `"a:b:c:d"`.

You don't have that in your code sample, and it accepts `-d` with no arguments just fine.

Perhaps you took it off when writing your test case? The [tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/bash/info) step 2 for posting says to "Test your example. Make sure it runs and still shows the problem. Do not brush this off."